# Is it possible to have drag and drop functionality with AngularJS without relying on jQuery UI?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I've seen http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/list, but this requires jQuery and jQuery UI. If possible, I'd like to not have those dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AngularJS documentation SURPRISINGLY has an example of this on the Compiler page. [Check it out.](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) You may have to add to it, but it is a great simple example of how to write a directive to get the draggable functionality.

Comment: How can I create a custom "drop" function?

Comment: well, isn't that convenient!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [ngDraggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable) is designed to support drag-drop functionality without dependency of jQuery UI.

I did some spike and it worked well on PC browsers, however, it still has some UI issues on mobile so far. Here is a [live demo](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example.html).